# Many to many relationship in Drift with subquery for referencing list

Tags: sqlite, dart, orm, drift

I am using [drift](https://pub.dev/packages/drift) orm and existing models for my database from package **A**. Models in that package rely on [**dart_mappable**](https://pub.dev/packages/dart_mappable).

I am trying to define 2 tables: **Items** and **Attribute**.
In existing model **Item** contains a list of **Attribute**.

How to define subquery or something to achieve desired result.

```dart
@UseRowClass(Item)
class Items extends Table {
  IntColumn get id => integer().unique()();
  /* More columns */
  List<Attribute> get attributes => ...
}

@UseRowClass(Attribute)
class Tags extends Table {
  IntColumn get id => integer().unique()();
  /* More columns */
}

@DataClassName('ItemAttributeEntry')
class ItemAttributeEntries extends Table {
  IntColumn get itemId => integer().references(Item, #id)();
  IntColumn get attributeId  => integer().references(Attribute, #id)();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are looking for a query to retrieve a list of all items with their list of attributes each, all at once. I don't think that is possible in a single query.

You can use [joins](https://drift.simonbinder.eu/docs/advanced-features/joins/#joins) to combine the two tables in a query based on the `itemId`. However, that only makes sense if you group the results with [group by](https://drift.simonbinder.eu/docs/advanced-features/joins/#group-by) and use an aggregate function on the attributes, e.g. to get the number of attributes for each item.

You cannot return a list of multiple attributes in a single SQL attribute. SQL insists on using an aggregate function if you use `GROUP BY`.

You can try it yourself [here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_groupby1): Change the query to

```
SELECT ShipperName, OrderDate,
   (SELECT * FROM ORDERS WHERE Orders.ShipperID = Shippers.ShipperID) AS "AllOrders"
FROM Orders;
```

You will get the following error message:
`You have written a subquery that can return more than one field without using the EXISTS reserved word in the main query's FROM clause. Revise the SELECT statement of the subquery to request only one field.`

---

You could probably return the attributes (or attribute IDs) as a string of comma-separated values, but that's a dirty solution.

I suggest that you write a query to get the attributes for a single given item. It could look something like this:

```
final query = select(items).join([
   innerJoin(attributes, attributes.itemId.equalsExp(items.id)),
]);
```

If you really need all attributes right when your app launches, you could maybe do a join without `GROUP BY`. That gives you tuples of items and attributes (with duplicate items), which you could reduce to `Item` objects with some kind of mapper function.

---

**EDIT:**

I had a similar problem working on my app, with a one-to-many relationship of entity A to entity B. I used a [StreamTransformer](https://api.dart.dev/be/176281/dart-async/StreamTransformer-class.html) to transform the tuples of entities to objects of type A with a list property for the related B entities.