# How to make a select query on a many-to-many relationship using Flutter Drift?

Tags: flutter, drift

In my Flutter app, I have 2 entities, with a many to many relationship:

- Account
- Tag

```
@DataClassName("AccountDTO")
class Accounts extends Table
{
  IntColumn get id => integer().autoIncrement()();
  TextColumn get name => text().withLength(min: 1, max: 256)();
  TextColumn get login => text().nullable().withLength(min: 0, max: 256)();
}

@DataClassName("TagDTO")
class Tags extends Table
{
  IntColumn get id => integer().autoIncrement()();
  TextColumn get label => text().withLength(min: 1, max: 32)();
}
```

An account can have 0, one or multiple tags, and a tag can be assigned to 0, one or multiple accounts.

So I created a third table:

```
@DataClassName("AccountTagDTO")
class AccountsTags extends Table
{
  IntColumn get id => integer().autoIncrement()();
  IntColumn get accountId => integer().references(Accounts, #id)();
  IntColumn get tagId => integer().references(Tags, #id)();
}
```

And this class:

```
class AccountWithTags
{
  final AccountDTO accountDTO;
  final List<TagDTO> listTagDTO;
  AccountWithTags(this.accountDTO, this.listTagDTO);
}
```

Now I need to do something very basic: get a specific account by id and its associated tags.

So far, here is what I tried (it doesn't compile):

```
Future<AccountWithTags?> getAccountWithTagsById(int idAccount) async
{
  final row = await ((select(accountsTags)).join([
    leftOuterJoin(tags, tags.id.equalsExp(accountsTags.tagId)),
  ])..where(accountsTags.accountId.equals(idAccount))).getSingleOrNull();
  if (row == null) return null;

  return AccountWithTags(
    row.readTable(accounts),
    row.readTable(tags),
  );
}
```

Actually, I don't know how to proceed, since there is very few documentation on the internet about it (and yes, I've already checked [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75651339/many-to-many-relationship-in-drift-with-subquery-for-referencing-list) and [the official documentation](https://www.google.com/url?client=internal-element-cse&cx=002567324444333206795:_yptu7lact8&q=https://drift.simonbinder.eu/docs/examples/relationships/&sa=U&ved=2ahUKEwixvteFgP2AAxXT2gIHHVanB14QFnoECAUQAQ&usg=AOvVaw1lKw4CHSK_dzsUoNiS-Wij), but I'm still stuck).

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

OK so I had to do it in 2 steps:

1. make a basic request to get the desired account
2. make another request using a left join to get the associated tags

Here is my working function:

```
Future<AccountWithTags?> getAccountWithTagsById(int idAccount) async
{
  final accountDTO = await (select(accounts)..where((t) => t.id.equals(id))).getSingleOrNull();
  if (accountDTO == null) return null;

  final queryTags = (select(accountsTags)).join([
    leftOuterJoin(tags, tags.id.equalsExp(accountsTags.tagId)),
  ])..where(accountsTags.accountId.equals(idAccount));

  final listTagsDTO = (await queryTags.get()).map((e) => e.readTable(tags)).toList();
  return AccountWithTags(accountDTO, listTagsDTO);
}
```